# Animating pieces of a sprite sheet in Cocos2D for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm using Cocos2D 0.99.5 for iPhone in Xcode 3.2.5.  There doesn't seem to be much useful information to **animate pieces of a sprite sheet**. This is all I'm trying to accomplish. A few attempts with info I found online are deprecated.  I want it to work fine with my version of Cocos2D.

I know exactly the CGRect coordinates I need to use to test my first sprites 2 frames.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered fairly well with the Sprite basics in the Cocos2D programming guide:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:sprites

Comment: Thanks. I only glanced over that link before and as soon as I saw more than one filename with different numbers I assumed that they weren't using just one image.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a tool for exactly this purpose

http://www.darkfunction.com